# Retain django form data even if validation using recaptcha fialed

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am writing a contact form for my website, and I am using reCaptcha to validate the user prior form submission. I can't figure out how to structure my logics so that if reCaptcha fails, I can still redirect the user to the same page WITHOUT deleting the fields that they already have typed.

In my views.py I have the followings.

```
class hdnytorv(View):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ContextObject = ContextBuilder() #building a dict with context keywords
        

        if 'contactFrom' in kwargs: #Then this comes from a post that has failed and data needs to be saved
            self.form = kwargs['contactForm']
        else:
            self.form = contactForm()
        
        self.context = {'contactForm' : self.form}
    
    #When the page is generated first the below will be shown
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        ..
        return render(request, template_name='welcome.html', context = self.context)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        form = contactForm(request.POST)
        newsletterForm = newsLetterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            #check recaptcha 
            validate = Validate(request = request)
            validate.result['success'] =False
            if validate.result['success'] is False:
                messages.warning(request, 'Validation failed. Try again.', extra_tags='contactSubmitStatus')
                return redirect('/welcomePage#contactForm')
```

The problem is everytime I redirect to `'/welcomPage#contactForm' a new class instance will be made and the get will be called and the form will be rerendered so all the fields are empty and user's data input is lost. What should I do to have a solution that fulfills the below 2 criteria:

1. Redirect back to the same page with data in the form
2. Redirect to the correct id tag of the page which in my example is #contactForm

Comment: One cannot redirect with data. Just process the form after validating the captcha what stops you from doing that? Or simply render back the same page with the form instead of redirecting.

Comment: The problem is if recaptcha validation failed. I need to retain all the user inputs in the form fields. I know that one cannot redirect with context. If I redirect to the same page, then the get method above will be called, and the data that user has put in form fields are lost. 

I can rerender back to the same page welcome.html, but I need to show the page at a specific tag. I don't want to take the user to the top of the page. Is that possible with render?